# Decrement DateTimePicker day value with customized time

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I want to decrement the day in `DateTimePicker` when button is clicked and keep the customized  `time` at `10:00:00`.

When I use the following code and when going back from month to another (previous month on the same year) it works fine.

but the problem comes when I try to go back from 2016 to 2015. For example when I try to go back from `1-1-2016` to `31-12-2015` it gives error: "Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime"

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.Year, dateTimePicker1.Value.Month, dateTimePicker1.Value.Day - 1, 10, 00, 0);
```

Anyone knows how can I decrease the day and keep customized time when going back from year to another (previous year)? please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dateTimePicker1.Value` is a `DateTime` and `DateTime` has methods to modify dates and times correctly

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.AddDays(-1).AddHours(10);
```

It takes current date [midnight], calculates previous date [still midnight] and adds 10 hours [morning]

Comment: This code decreases the day but did not keep the time customized at 10am. any idea? thank you

Comment: @Serena, please, check `dataTimePicker1.Value` before updating. if it is smth like `1-1-2016` (without `10:00`), then `dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(-1).AddHours(10);` should help

Comment: I add the AddHours(10) but it gives random time value every time I click the button.  every time i click the button the time changes to different value and not stay at 10am.

Comment: @Serena, another modification here: `dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.AddDays(-1).AddHours(10);`. It takes current date (midnight), calculates previous date (still midnight) and adds 10 hours (morning :)). i hope this helps

Comment: Now it worked well :) please update the answer so I can up vote you .thank you